# Difference between echoing json_encode and returning it in ajax

Tags: php, json

I think this may be classified as basic but I was curious. Why do you have to parse json encoded data returned from ajax calls but not if it is echoed by php in the main loading document?

**Edit**: Basically the question is, if I have an object called `data` with a property `id` in both cases, why I can type

```
data.id
```

and have the value returned when the json object has been echoed out while loading the main document, but have it throw an error when returned from an ajax call and not parsed?

Comment: Possible answer. Because php "echoes" generate html from your json. Html that can be used by your browser. In your javascript, you parse your json to transform it into html...

Comment: Seems logical, doh! But then again, why is the html not parsed automatically when the datatype is html?

Comment: mhm... You can call ajax, and get html formatted answer. In the succes callback, `$("#element").html(data);` works. So I suppose we can do `$("#element").append(data);`

Comment: You don't seem to understand the question. I'm asking about json.

Comment: You talked about datatype html... sorry, I didn't understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By echoed, I assume you mean you did something like this:

```
<script>
  var data = <? echo json_encode($data) ?>;

  alert(data.id);
</script>
```

If that's the case, the browser knows that the echoed json is code because it's contained by script tags. JSON is a subset of JavaScript, so what you're really doing here is generating JavaScript code that the browser then interprets.

Ajax, on the other hand is different. When you load something with ajax, it might be text, xml, csv, html, svg, or any of dozens of different formats. JSON is just a data format like all the others I listed, so you've got to tell the javascript engine what it is. That's why you have to parse it. It needs to know the format of the text so it can interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have to*, and JSON-encoded strings still need to be "decoded" from Javascript. It's just a faster way of being able to access array elements/properties in the returned string for ajax calls.

Comment: I mean why can I access array elements/properties with echoed json data without decoding it as I would in ajax ?